# Configuration file for a shell script to do dynamic addition of files -ubuntu

Tags: bash, shell, ubuntu, configuration-files

I have this shell script myScript.sh
I am trying to write a configuration file which sets the environment variables. But since I am a linux novice, I am getting confused as to how to do it.

So this is how myScript.sh looks.

```
export $SERVICE_ROOT=/home/myPath
export $FILE1PATH=/home/myPath/file1
export $FILE2PATH=/home/myPath/file2

...
$SERVICE_ROOT/bin/integration.bin \
$FILE1PATH \
$FILE2PATH \
. . .
$FILENPATH

python pythonScript.py --arguments
```

Now, I have to put all the hard coding into the config files. As in multiple users may want to make changes. So I am writing a config.sh which looks like this.

```
SERVICE="/home/myPath"
FILE1PATH=/home/myPath/file1
FILE2PATH=/home/myPath/file2
```

Within the new myscript.sh I call

```
export $SERVICE
export $FILEPATH1
export $FILEPATH2
```

1) But my issue is am I doing the right things in the first place? Somehow setting environment variables despite having a config file doesn't make sense but I am not able to figure out how else to do it.

2) There are chances that a user may add FILEPATHM etc beyond the N.So how should I modify myScript.sh to dynamically export the new files names beyond n?

3) I need to call the python script within my shell script but the name may change from one user to another. So how do i declare the exact command

```
python pythonScript.py --arguments
```

without executing it in the config file but I should be able to execute that command inside my shell script whenever I want to. I was trying to use the

`python bla bla` commands but did not understand the correct way of doing it.

Any help will be much appreciated

Comment: Do you need to export those variables? Are the visible to or needed in child processes? That is, are they only used in the shell script or are they referred to in the Python script? Are you sourcing one shell script from another or running it?

Comment: @DennisWilliamson I don't actually have to export them as long as I can use their value within my script. Only the script uses all these variables not the python though. I am just running the config file within my shell script and not really sourcing it.

Answer (score 1):

It's unclear which file does what and how they fit together. Is one file a replacement for another? Does one file create another? I think it would be helpful if you clarified things a bit.

Based on what I think you want:

myScript.sh:

```
#!/bin/bash
. ./config.sh

. . .
"$SERVICE_ROOT/bin/integration.bin" \
"$FILE1PATH" \
"$FILE2PATH" \
. . .
"$FILENPATH"

python pythonScript.py --arguments
```

config.sh:

```
SERVICE_ROOT="/home/myPath"
FILE1PATH=/home/myPath/file1
FILE2PATH=/home/myPath/file2
```

The `source` command (or `.`) reads in the named file and executes it as if it were actually part of the calling script. It's closely analogous to other languages' `include` statements.

A more dynamic version might look like this:

myScript.sh:

```
#!/bin/bash
. ./config.sh

. . .
"$SERVICE_ROOT/bin/integration.bin" "${filepaths[@]}"
```

config.sh:

```
SERVICE_ROOT="/home/myPath"
filepaths=(
    /home/myPath/file1
    /home/myPath/file2
)
```

This version uses an array to hold the paths. Additional paths can be added on separate lines between the parentheses. All the paths are supplied at once as arguments when `${filepaths[@]}"` is expanded.

Comment: Thank you for helping me with the sourcing of the file. I was going wrong with that part which was hindering the progress of my script. The for loop is exactly what I want to implement. I will try it out and let you know how it went

Comment: @user1357576: `for` loop? I don't see one.

Comment: Sorry... I meant array.. Wonder why I typed for loop.. Sorry about that